# Find the volume $V$ as a result of revolving the region between $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$ and $g(x) = x$ around the line $y = 4$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

For context, I'm self-studying calculus and am doing some practice problems to test my understanding of solids of revolution. I want to ask:

### Are my solutions (using both Disc and Shell Integration) to the following question correct and efficient? (As in not overcomplicating things.) Also, is each step justified?

> **Find the volume $V$ as a result of revolving the region between $f(x) = x^2 - 2x$ and $g(x) = x$ around the line $y = 4$.**

I used [**Desmos**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y97znhu8sn) to help me visualize the problem:

[image: [Red, Green, Blue regions]]

(This will particularly be helpful for the Shell Method solution).

#### • *Disc Method* (or specifically *the Washer Method* for hollow solids of revolution): Integrating *parallel* to the axis of revolution

$$\begin{align*}
    V &= \int_a^b \pi\, (4 - f(x))^2 - \pi\, (4 - g(x))^2 \,dx \tag{$\scriptsize f(x)=g(x) \iff x^2 - 2x = x$} \\
      &= \pi \int_0^3 (4 - x^2 + 2x)^2 - (4 - x)^2 \,dx \tag{$\scriptsize x(x - 3) = 0 \implies x = 0 = a \lor x = 3 = b$} \\ 
      &= \pi \int_0^3 (x^4 - 4x^3 - 5x^2 + 24x) \,dx\\
      & = \pi \,\left.\left(\frac{x^5}{5} - x^4 - \frac{5x^3}{3} + 12x^2 \right)\right|_0^3 \\
      & = \pi \left(\frac{243}{5} - 81 - \frac{135}{3} + 108\right)\\
      & = \pi\left(\frac{243 - 405 -225 + 540}{5}\right)\!, \\[7pt]
    V &= \frac{153\pi}{5} \text{ units}^3. \;\llap{\mathrel{\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid red]{\phantom{V = \frac{153\pi}{5} \text{ units}^3.}}}}
\end{align*}$$

#### • *Shell Method*: Integrating *perpendicular* to the axis of revolution

$$\begin{align*}
    f^{-1}(y) &= \begin{cases}
                  1 - \sqrt{y + 1}, &\text{if $\,x \leq 1$} \\
                  1 + \sqrt{y + 1}, &\text{if $\,x \geq 1$.}
                 \end{cases} \\[5pt]
    g^{-1}(y) &= x. \\[5pt]
    V &= \overbrace{\color{red}{\text{Revolved Red Region}}}^{\color{red}{R}} \,+\, \overbrace{\color{green}{\text{Revolved Green Region}}}^{\color{green}{G}} \,+\, \overbrace{\color{blue}{\text{Revolved Blue Region}}}^{\color{blue}{B}} \\[5pt]
    &= \underbrace{\color{red}{\int_{-1}^0 2\pi (4 - y) (1 - [1 - \sqrt{y + 1}]) \,dy}}_{\color{red}{R}} \,+ \underbrace{\color{green}{\int_{-1}^0 2\pi (4 - y) ([1 + \sqrt{y + 1}] - 1) \,dy}}_{\color{green}{G}} \,+ \\ &\phantom{=}\; \underbrace{\color{blue}{\int_0^3 2\pi (4 - y) ([1 + \sqrt{y + 1}] - y) \,dy}}_{\color{blue}{B}}. \\[5pt]
    \frac{V}{2\pi} &= \color{red}{\int_{-1}^0 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy} \,+ \color{green}{\int_{-1}^0 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy} \,+ \color{blue}{\int_0^3 (4 - y) \,dy} \,+ \\
    &\phantom{=}\; \color{blue}{\int_0^3 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy}\,+ \color{blue}{\int_0^3 (y^2 - 4y) \,dy} \\[5pt] 
    &= \underbrace{\color{purple}{\int_{-1}^3 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy}}_{\text{Let } u \,=\, y \,+\, 1 \implies du \,=\, dy} \,+ \underbrace{\color{green}{\int_{-1}^0 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy}}_{\text{Let } u \,=\, y \,+\, 1 \implies du \,=\, dy} \,+ \color{blue}{\int_0^3 (y^2 - 5y + 4) \,dy} \\[5pt]
    &= \color{purple}{\int_{u=0}^{u=4} (5 - u) \sqrt{u} \;du} \,+ \color{green}{\int_{u=0}^{u=1} (5 - u) \sqrt{u} \;du} \,+ \color{blue}{\frac{1}{3} (3)^3} - \color{blue}{\frac{5(3)^2}{2}} + \color{blue}{4(3)} \\[5pt]
    &= \color{purple}{\left(\frac{10}{3} (4) \sqrt{4} - \frac{2}{5} (4)^2 \sqrt{4}\right)} + \color{green}{\left(\frac{10}{3} (1) \sqrt{1} - \frac{2}{5} (1)^2 \sqrt{1}\right)} -\, \color{blue}{\frac{3}{2}} \\[5pt]
    &= \color{purple}{\frac{208}{15}} + \color{green}{\frac{44}{15}} - \color{blue}{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{416 + 88 - 45}{30} = \frac{459}{30} = \frac{153}{10}, \\[5pt]
    V &= \frac{153}{10} \cdot 2\pi, \\[7pt]
    V &= \frac{153\pi}{5} \text{ units}^3. \;\llap{\mathrel{\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid red]{\phantom{V = \frac{153\pi}{5} \text{ units}^3.}}}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: For a little more efficiency, combine the red and green integrals into one.$$(1-(1-\sqrt{y+1})) + ((1+\sqrt{y+1}) - 1) = 2\sqrt{y+1}$$

Comment: @user170231 I considered doing that too but that will leave $\color{blue}{\int_0^3 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy} =  \color{blue}{\int_{u=1}^{u=4} (5 - u) \sqrt{u} \;du}$ and I didn't want to evaluate $\color{blue}{\left.\left(\frac{10}{3} u \sqrt{u} - \frac{2}{5} u^2 \sqrt{u}\right)\right|_1^4}$ when I can evaluate $\color{purple}{\int_{-1}^3 (4 - y) \sqrt{y + 1} \;dy} =  \color{purple}{\int_{u=0}^{u=4} (5 - u) \sqrt{u} \;du} = \color{purple}{\left.\left(\frac{10}{3} u \sqrt{u} - \frac{2}{5} u^2 \sqrt{u}\right)\right|_0^4}$ instead.

Comment: Looks good. One nitpicky note: We usually put parentheses around an integrand which is a sum or difference, for example $\int_0^3 (x^4-4x^3-5x^2+24x)\, dx$ and not $\int_0^3 x^4-4x^3-5x^2+24x\, dx$. The one line $\int_a^b \pi(4-f(x))^2 - (4-g(x))^2\, dx$ is definitely missing parentheses or another $\pi$ or something.

Comment: @aschepler Ah, I see, I'll edit it now, thank you.